# AngularJS: Anchor links (for external visitors, not internal)

Tags: angularjs

I have an angularJS website such as:
`www.website.com/products/[productname]#[reviewername]`
where

- there are several products.
- each product has a page
- each product page has user reviews

I want people to be able to share a link (such as on Facebook) of a specific review.  So if someone clicks on the full link or pastes it into their browser, it scrolls to that review (like a normal anchor link).

I am able to use ScrollTo for links within the same page.  However I am unable to get the full url to work for people from outside the site.

Comment: @pankaj-parkar isn't the duplicate marked only for links from one part of the site to another?  How would I do this for someone typing the whole url into the browser?

Comment: @phil isn't the duplicate marked only for links from one part of the site to another? How would I do this for someone typing the whole url into the browser?